# Compute the probability $P(X>Y)$

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous random variables whose joint density function is given by $f(x, y) = 2e^{−x−2y}$, for $x, y ≥ 0$, and $f(x, y) = 0$ elsewhere. Compute the probability $P(X>Y)$.

I know that I have to integrate two times $f(x,y)$ in $dy$ and $dx$ but which integration limit should I use? From $0$ to infinite for $x$ and from $0$ to $y$ for y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** using the defintion of $f$. the solution is $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^xf(x,y)\,dy\right)dx$

Comment: Thank you, now I have the correct value :)

Comment: But usually in order to calculate the probability is dx and then dy, why here is the other way around? Is not relevant?

Comment: @FabioTaccaliti it depends on the expression which you wanna compute. For example for $P(X<Y)$ you must change the $x$ and $y$.